# Compativilidades whitelist

Tags: ios, cordova, plugin

Tengo una app android que ya corre sin problema. Ahora estamos pasando su desarrollo a iOS.

Destacar que es hibrida con cordova.

Estoy mirando compatividad de los plugins, y me esta cascando con el `cordova-plugin-whitelist` a la hora de compilar.

Me he fijado que en la pagina del [plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) pone que es compatible con Android 4 o superiores, nada de iOS.

¿Sabéis si es posible usarlo? o ¿existe alguna alternativa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible usarlo sin problema alguno, dentro de los quebraderos de cabeza que da Cordova a veces... Además yo lo uso en alguna de mis aplicaciones.

En la documentación en inglés no aparece nada de IOS, pero en la documentación en español sí dice que es compatible.

[Documentación en español](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/tree/master/doc/es)

En este enlace, que forma parte de la documentación del plugin, puedes además entender un poco más el plugin si vas un poco pegado en inglés.